# Output quality of various compilation methods

Tags: compiling

I read from the *LaTeX WikiBook* that *in order to achieve the highest quality output we should choose the shortest compilation route*. However I found no clear explanation for this, except the vague remark that in each step some information may be lost.

Is it true that `pdflatex` produces better quality output than `latex`+`dvipdfm` or that `latex`+`dvipdfm` produces better output than `latex`+`dvips`+`ps2pdf`? If so what is better and why is there this difference?

Comment: Better means foremost to avoid Type-3 fonts like `dvips` might introduce them. These are bitmap fonts that don't scale well. Other aspects of quality could be file size, links within a PDF and other PDF specialties.

Comment: I didn't want to suggest that PDFLaTeX produces the best quality but just name some aspects of quality that could be compared among solutions. Another one that I missed could be font encodings such that cut-copy-paste from the final document works reliably.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

pdfLaTeX provides microtypographic extensions such as font expansion and character protrusion, providing better optical justification. Further it directly supports PDF features.

Classical LaTeX compiles to DVI. It has to hide PDF features within DVI special commands.

Have a look at:

- The [pdfTeX manual](http://sarovar.org/docman/view.php/106/66/pdftex-s.pdf)
- [Micro-typographic extensions to the TeX typesetting system](http://www.pragma-ade.com/pdftex/thesis.pdf)

Both documents are written by Hàn Thế Thành, the originakl developer of pdfTeX.